# Eclipse C++ multiple projects common files

Tags: c++, eclipse

In Eclipse/CDT, I wish to have several C++ projects (projA, projB, projC, etc.) that will all include some `.c`, `.cpp` and/or `.h` files from a common directory.  Here is my existing file structure:

```
Workspace -> projA -> src
          -> common ->src : a.c a.h  b.cpp  c.cpp  d.c  etc.
          -> projB -> src
          -< projC -> src
```

When I attempt to add a source file in ../common/src to projA, the Add a Source File tool complains that the file must be in the project.

So, how do I include, say ../common/src/a.c into ../projA -> src?

Comment: You should ask yourself if these shared files form a library that you should compile/link on its own.

Comment: ADDITION:  Eclipse version is Juno running on Ubuntu 123.04 64-bit

Comment: ANSWER: @mohaps got the right best solution for me in Linux.  However, a version difference or some such made his last instruction turn into:   Right Click the new folder then Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Add Folder then select the new folder by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has an option called add new source folder and an option in that dialogue to link to existing directory. You can link the "common" folder as a source folder in all of the projects pointing to the same directory.

Right click on project -> New -> Folder -> Advanced -> Link to alternate location

Once folder has been added,

Right click on Folder -> Buld Path -> Use as source folder

Comment: right-click projA.  New->Source FOlder does no give me anything but a list of the directories in my Project directory (../projA).  I get no options of any kind.

Comment: New->Folder... not New-> Source Folder. click the "advanced" button on bottom left. Select the radio button that says "Link to alternate location" Once Folder has been added right click and do "Build Path" -> "Use as source folder"

Comment: Disregard that last comment.  I didn't follow the instructions.  Mea culpa.

Comment: Now, when I right click I don't get a Build-Path choice.  You do mean right click on the "common-src" enty that is in my Project Explorer window, right?

Comment: No Build-Path.  I have:  New : Go Into : Copy : Delete : Move : Rename... : Export... : Import... : Refresh : Make Targets...  : Show in Remote System view... : Run as... : Debug as... : Profile as... : Compare with... : Restore from Local History.. : Run C/C++ Code Analysis Team : : Properties : Resource Configurations...

Comment: Hey, I think I found it.  Right Click the new folder then Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Add Folder then select the new folder by name.

Comment: ah, looks like we have different eclipse versions

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to drag the files or root folder from "common" to "projA" while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and releasing it on the target "src" folder. Eclipse will prompt you with the option to copy the files or link them from the original folder. After linking, they will be built as part of the target project (e.g., "projA").

Here's the prompt I get when releasing a folder:

[image: file and folder operation prompt]

I think the second option accomplishes what you want (I haven't messed with the third option).

Comment: It this a linux answer?  I am running Juno on Ubuntu Precise.  How did you get to this dialog?

Comment: @WesMiller I'm running on Windows. I tested this in both Indigo and Juno with the same results. I would be stunned if there is no Linux equivalent available, given the general OS-neutrality of Eclipse.

Comment: I agree.  I still know no way to get to any dialog that looks like the one you included.  I wonder it @mohaps got us to the same place.  Thanks for your help.